# Cannot see mouse events

Tags: c#, canvas

I am currently implementing an application (neural network like) in C# where I could add neurons and associate them using several events (mouse, keyboard, touch, leap motion ...). Anyway I am modifying some things in my code to make it cleaner and more generic as it should have been since the start.

The question I have here is about events. I know how it is working and I managed to build a listener for mouse or touch events. My application can be seen as :

- a Canvas (the Window)
- a VisualBox

My VisualBox is a better Grid with more attributes. It contains a Viewbox which itself contains a custom Shape. So to resume I have

- Canvas
- VisualBox
- Viewbox
- Shape

As my VisualBox is a Grid, I can attach events to it and even if I have done that, the only thing that my events are pointing is my Shape. Basically my sender is always of type Shape.

Does anyone know what should I do / specify to see my VisualBox as the pointed object without navigating through the Shape Parents ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to get access to a base object even though the sender of the event is higher up in the inheritance hierarchy? If that is the case you can chain events through the object hierarchy down to your shape class or the easier approach is if you have access to the shape object when the event fires you can just include a reference to the object when you initialize the event arguments.

```
public class InheritedShapeEventArgs : EventArgs //or some other event argument class
{

  public InheritedShapeEventArgs(Shape shape)
  {
     this.Shape = shape;
  {
  public Shape Shape { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: I used the IsEnabled property of my Shape. I put it to "false" then I can see the events on my Grid. Is it ok to do or should I avoid that? I would prefer to avoid having my events mapped on a lot of objects (Grid + Shape) which target the same object.

Comment: There is no issue with using a property to decide whether or not to fire the event. If we could see the object hierarchy, and the object firing the event and it would be much easier to help you